# Is it possible to check heap memory usage by pool?

Tags: java, optimization, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I've been working on optimizing a program that was having a lot of issues with memory leaks. The leaks are gone now, but the occasional runs of the major GC still put a good dent in PS old gen. I know that I can check basic overall memory information through Runtime, but is it possible to check usage in PS eden, PS survivor, and PS old from within the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://jaxenter.com/an-introduction-to-garbage-collection-106154.html) can help you out

You can write custom code to analyze memory & output will be in the form

```
collection time: 82037
collection count: 116
PS Survivor Space: init = 1703936(1664K) used = 65536(64K) committed = 32047104(31296K) max = 32047104(31296K)
PS Eden Space: init = 10551296(10304K) used = 0(0K) committed = 69795840(68160K) max = 113049600(110400K)
PS Old Gen: init = 27983872(27328K) used = 239432344(233820K) committed = 357957632(349568K) max = 357957632(349568K)
Code Cache: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 19949568(19482K) committed = 20185088(19712K) max = 50331648(49152K)
PS Perm Gen: init = 21757952(21248K) used = 148450536(144971K) committed = 155058176(151424K) max = 268435456(262144K)
```

Good [read](http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-start-investigating-javas.html)

Answer (score 0):

**jstat Tool** - Java Virtual Machine Statistics Monitoring Tool is the thing which is used to monitor the usage of JVM.

please go through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html):

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm talking about monitoring it from withing the program that is running. I'm aware of my options for inspecting from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Runtime class to get the heap memory details.

```
public class GetHeapMemory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    }
}
```